# How can I view in-memory strings of a process on Linux (Ubuntu)?

Tags: dynamic-analysis, strings

On Windows, I can use tools like Process Explorer and Process Hacker to view in-memory strings generated at runtime of a given process. How can I accomplish this same task on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [gcore](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcore.1.html) utility to generate the [core dump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_dump) which can be examined with [gdb debugger](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gdb) (or [strings](https://linux.die.net/man/1/strings) utility) and should contain the full memory image.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to read a process's memory in Linux isto read the psaudo-file `/proc/<PID>/mem`, which provides raw access to the memory space, as seen by the process, at offsets retrieved from `/proc/<PID>/maps`, which provides information about how the memory is laid out.